# Using a single function recursively to display a triangle with a minimum and maximum value

Tags: c++, recursion

This is a simple homework question, but I've been unable to solve it and honestly am wondering if it's even possible within the parameters that have been set.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void triangle(int m, int n);
void drawline(char symbol, int len);

int main() {
    triangle(3,5);
    return 0;
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void triangle(int m, int n) {
    // use recursion to complete this function
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void drawline(char symbol, int len) {
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        cout << symbol;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Once the recursion function is completed, the code above should return this.

```
***
****
*****
****
***
```

I can make it up to the fifth star on line 3, but iterating backwards and stopping at three stars is throwing me for a loop. I need to have some type of value that stays at m's initial value and the same for n. I can't figure this out without changing m, and if I change m then I have lost my terminating point. I don't know if there is some strange math trick I should be doing with m and n, or if this is just something simple and I'm missing it.

If the triangle started at 0 every time, then this would be cake. It's keeping the minimum point that is throwing me for a loop. I'm not asking for the answer, but just a confirmation that this is possible without doing something hacky and a nudge in the right direction would be nice.

**I have searched all over and all I have found is triangles that either always start at 0, or they use a function for the first half of the triangle and another for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
void triangle(int m, int n)
{
   // Prevent stack overflow
   if ( m > n )
   {
      return;
   }

   // Draw m symbols.
   drawline('*', m);

   // If m and n are not equal, recurse.
   if ( m != n )
   {
      triangle(m+1,n);
      drawline('*', m);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python pseudocode:

```
>>> def triangle(m, n):
...   if m > n: return
...   if m < n: 
...     print '*' * m
...     triangle(m + 1, n)
...     print '*' * m
...   elif m == n:
...     print '*' * m
... 
>>> triangle(3, 5)
***
****
*****
****
***
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, 'n' is the "height" at the center of the pyramid, and 'm' is the height at the edges.  I'm assuming that 'n' must be greater than or equal to 'm', although you don't verify this.

Instead of thinking of building the pyramid from one edge to the other, think of drawing it from the outside to the middle.  So when you call your recursive `triangle` function, you draw one edge, recurse to draw the middle, then draw the other edge.  So, something like this:

```
triangle(m, n):
    if (m == n):
        drawline('*', m)
    else:        
        drawline('*', m)
        triangle(m+1, n)
        drawline('*', m)
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, but I am still running into an infinite loop (recursion?) with your method. I'll continue to debug and post back.

Comment: @PrometheanVR: What is it printing infinitely?  A single line?  The whole pyramid?  Empty lines?  Or is it printing nothing at all?

Comment: The function listed by R Sahu worked correctly. I feel like this is more of an issue of understanding void returns in recursive functions, which we have not been over in class. I spent a ton of time tonight trying to figure this out, instead of studying for our test tomorrow. I honestly feel retarded atm and not cut out for this degree.

Comment: @PrometheanVR: R Sahu's and mine should be logically equivalent.  Maybe you made an error translating my pseudocode into C++?  Maybe missing brackets?